# Avoid blank Items in ListView Delphi 10.4.2

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to display data from `TFDQuery` to `TListView`, but I don't want to use a Data Binding.

When I fetch the data, I have a blank Item between every record. How can I avoid these blank items?

```
DM.Qdomains.Connection := DM.Conn;
DM.Qdomains.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM domains';
DM.Qdomains.Active := True;
DM.Qdomains.First;
try
  while not DM.Qdomains.Eof do
  begin
    with DomainsListView.Items.Add do
    begin
      DomainsListView.Items.Add.Data['domain'] := DM.Qdomains.FieldByName('domain').AsString;
    end;
    DM.Qdomains.Next;
  end;
finally
  DM.Qdomains.Free;
end;
```

[image: Blank Items]

Comment: Notice that you call `Add` twice per row. Just remove the first one: `with  DomainsListView.Items.Add do`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `TListView.Items.Add()` *twice* per DB record:

```
with DomainsListView.Items.Add do // <-- 1st call
begin
  DomainsListView.Items.Add.Data['domain'] := ...; // <-- 2nd call
end;
```

Simply get rid of the redundant `Add()` call, eg:

```pascal
DM.Qdomains.Connection := DM.Conn;
DM.Qdomains.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM domains';
DM.Qdomains.Active := True;
DM.Qdomains.First;
try
  while not DM.Qdomains.Eof do
  begin
    DomainsListView.Items.Add.Data['domain'] := DM.Qdomains.FieldByName('domain').AsString;
    DM.Qdomains.Next;
  end;
finally
  DM.Qdomains.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't have this single text, so I think your ListView appearance is Dynamic ?
I agree Remy's response, but I can't but ask why you don't use Livebindings to fill your ListView (so easy and no code) ?

(sorry to put this as an answer, but low reputation => no comment nor vote)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I don't know how to use live binding, can you tell me please how to do it?

Comment: It's easy, click right on listview and use 'link visually' (or something like that, I have a French version)

Comment: I can only direct you to my French blog i.e this entry https://www.developpez.net/forums/blogs/138527-sergiomaster/b5093/delphi-obtenir-liste-groupee-livebindings-suite/ and say Google trad (or any other) is your friend.

Comment: Thank you Serge I speak French more than English :)

Comment: so you can use developpez.net delphi forum to ask me for Livebindings I have more than one tutorials about  ;-)